# How to get the Friday of the current week as a date in the form of "yyyy-mm-dd" in R

Tags: r, date

The title says it all, but in case I wasn't clear enough I'll give a scenario:

Let's say I run my program next week. I would like my variable to return the date in the form of yyyy-mm-dd for the Friday of that week. Whether I run it on Monday or Wednesday or whenever, my variable is the date of the Friday of that week.

Comment: What have you tried? What are other conditions, if you run it on Friday is the date next Friday? What if you run during a weekend?

Comment: Also, weekday start can be different i.e Sunday or Monday

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A date will give you its 'weekday'. If you convert to `POSIXlt` you get it via the `wday` field.  As Friday has a value of 5, you just add the difference to 5 to the date.

Function:

```
getFriday <- function(d) d + (5 - as.POSIXlt(d)$wday)
```

Examples for this week's Monday and Wednesday:

```
> getFriday(as.Date("2021-07-25")) 
[1] "2021-07-30" 
> getFriday(as.Date("2021-07-27")) 
[1] "2021-07-30" 
>
```

You can easily control for inputs that a Sat or Sun, and error out, or adjust accordingly.  But the key is that this *is* computable as a difference from your input date to its desired next Friday. (And of course you should check that the input is a date, or convertible to a date, and error out if not ...)